# Static socket error when creating a LAN tcp server on Android (C#)

Tags: c#, android, sockets, tcp, server

I'm trying to make a LAN server that can transfer integers and strings between android devices over a local router. The c# code works with system.net directives, however produces an error saying "The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item".

Are we being idiots?

Thanks

```
using System;
using Android.Systems;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Net;
using Java.Net;



namespace My_App
{
    [Activity(Label = "My_App", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bt_client);

            button.Click += delegate {

                static Socket sck;


                sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
                try
                {
                    sck.Connect("127.0.0.1", 1234);
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to connect to remote end point! \r\n");
                }
                Console.Write("Enter Text");
                String text = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

                sck.Send(data);
                Console.Write("Data Sent \r\n");
                Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
                Console.Read();
                sck.Close();

            };

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the MSDN on [Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx):

> C# does not support static local variables (variables that are declared in method scope).

And since a [delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e.aspx) is a pointer to a method, that means you cannot declare static variables within a delegate. If you want your socket to be static, you must declare it at the class level.